# Joining Data into a Single Column

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have this table in access

Userinfo

| userid | Name | dept id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | JJ | 002 |
| 2 | KK | 001 |

Dept

| deptid | Dept Name |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | Testing |
| 002 | Sorting |
| 003 | Designing |

Checkinout

| userid | Name | Checktime | Checktype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | JJ | 2/5/2022 7:45:10 AM | 1 |
| 1 | JJ | 2/5/2022 18:00:10 PM | 0 |
| 1 | JJ | 2/6/2022 6:30:00 AM | 1 |
| 1 | JJ | 2/6/2022 18:10:30 PM | 0 |
| 2 | KK | 2/6/2022 6:10:30 AM | 1 |
| 2 | KK | 2/6/2022 18:20:30 PM | 0 |

But i want to create a Inner join that will show this table

| userid | Name | Deptname | In | Out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | JJ | Sorting | 2/5/2022 7:45:10 AM | 2/5/2022 18:00:10 PM |
| 1 | JJ | Sorting | 2/6/2022 6:30:00 AM | 2/6/2022 18:10:30 PM |
| 1 | KK | Testing | 2/6/2022 6:10:30 AM | 2/6/2022 18:20:30 PM |

This is the SQL that i used but i dont know how to put 0 as Out and 1 as In

```
SELECT Userinfo.userid as ID,UserInfo.Name as Name,Dept.DeptName as Dept , Checkinout.Checktime 



from ( Userinfo
inner join Checkinout on Userinfo.userid = Checkinout.userid )

inner join  Dept on Userinfo.DeptId =Dept.DeptId ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from the non-normalized Checkinout you can get everything but Out directly.  Then add a calculated field to the query to look up the appropriate Out Checktime for each In Checktime:

[image]

[image]

```
Out: (SELECT TOP 1 q.Checktime FROM  [Checkinout] as q WHERE  (q.userid = [Checkinout].[userid]) AND (q.Checktype = 0) AND  (q.Checktime > [Checkinout].[Checktime])  
ORDER BY q.Checktime ASC)

SQL:SELECT Userinfo.userid, Userinfo.Username, Dept.[Dept Name], Checkinout.Checktime AS [In], (SELECT TOP 1 q.Checktime FROM  [Checkinout] as q WHERE  (q.userid = [Checkinout].[userid]) AND (q.Checktype = 0) AND  (q.Checktime > [Checkinout].[Checktime])  
ORDER BY q.Checktime ASC) AS Out
FROM (Dept INNER JOIN Userinfo ON Dept.deptid = Userinfo.[dept id]) INNER JOIN Checkinout ON Userinfo.userid = Checkinout.userid
WHERE (((Checkinout.Checktype)=1))

'I used a nested query for the calculated field and calculated Out with the business rules that each user check-in must have a corresponding and later check-out by the same user without any check-in/check-outs between.
```

Comment: there is a problem in this formula it just get all of your last out

Comment: if you didnt out it will get the next out you did hahaha

Comment: I don't quite understand, but per the ending comment, if your business rules allow users to not clock out adapt the solution to handle that case based on the contraints your business rules give you.  Like if shifts must be 12 hours or less then use that to test for no sign out and handle that case (probably just mark it)